# Selenium Click a non-button element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

So I am trying to click a element that is not a button element, the html code is below:

```html
<div class="menu-item-header">
   <span class="header-title"><span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="icon-helper"></i></span>Help
   </span> <!--When a client clicks this it redirects them to the appropriate place (this is a React website)-->
</div>
```

The original website looks something like this:

```html
<div class="menu-item-header">
   <span class="header-title"><span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="icon-helper"></i></span>Help
   </span> <!---->
</div>
<div class="menu-item-header">
   <span class="header-title"><span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="icon-helper2"></i></span>Help2
   </span> <!---->
</div>
...
```

I have tried the following method to click the element:

```java
WebElement element = browser.findElement(...);
element.click();
```

however that did not work.

Comment: `however that did not work` What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so to click on the element with text as **Help** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='menu-item-header']/span[@class='header-title' and contains(., 'Help')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always default to JavaScript.

`driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('#<id>').click()");`

Or, if it only has a class identifier:

`driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('.<classname>')[0].click()")`

That being said, it does not meet accessibility standards to use spans or divs as buttons for functionality, so if you have access to the codebase, or can influence it, I would strongly suggest using a button instead.